# php upload script not uploading - but it is adding to database?

Tags: php, forms, file-upload

A weird problem when i am trying to make a banner art upload system for user profiles.

I have searched for answers, but none have solved it.

It is not a permissions problem, my chmod is 755 on uploads folder and in the upload.php file.

code below:

```
if ($_POST && !empty($_FILES)) {
$formOk = true;

//Assign Variables
$path = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
$name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
$size = $_FILES['image']['size'];
$type = $_FILES['image']['type'];

if ($_FILES['image']['error'] || !is_uploaded_file($path)) {
    $formOk = false;
    echo "Error: Error in uploading file. Please try again.";
}

//check file extension
if ($formOk && !in_array($type, array('image/png', 'image/x-png', 'image/jpeg', 'image/pjpeg', 'image/gif'))) {
    $formOk = false;
    echo "Error: Unsupported file extension. Supported extensions are JPG / PNG.";
}
// check for file size.
if ($formOk && filesize($path) > 500000) {
    $formOk = false;
    echo "Error: File size must be less than 3 MB.";
}

if ($formOk) {
    // read file contents
    $content = file_get_contents($path);

    //connect to mysql database
    if ($conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'hidden', 'hidden', 'hidden')) {
        $user_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['user_id']);
        $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['username']);
        $content = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $content);
    $sql = "insert into banners (user_id, username, name, size, type, content) values ('{$user_id}','{$username}','{$name}', '{$size}', '{$type}', '{$content}')";

        if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
            $uploadOk = true;
            $imageId = mysqli_insert_id($conn);
        } else {
            echo "Error: Could not save the data to mysql database. Please try again.";
        }

        mysqli_close($conn);
    } else {
        echo "Error: Could not connect to mysql database. Please try again.";
    }
}
```

And the form is:

```
        <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" >
      <div>
        <h3>Image Upload:</h3>
      </div>
      <div>
        <label>Image</label>
        <img src="<?php print_r($path); ?>"/>
        <?php print_r($_FILES); ?>
        <input type="text" name="user_id" value="<?php echo $user->data["user_id"]; ?>" readonly/>
        <br />
        <input type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo $user->data["username"]; ?>" readonly/>            
        <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="500000">
        <input type="file" name="image" />
        <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Upload">
      </div>
    </form>
```

I have the form in the same file upload.php along with my include header and footer.

So basically it stores the data into the database, but just will not upload what so ever, i also checked the phpinfo and so on, and all is ok, it is turned on, and file limit in phpinfo is 64mb, so i don't get why it wont upload?

any help would be appreciated, thanks

Comment: doesn't upload "where" exactly? In a folder?  I don't see `move_uploaded_file()` anywhere. *"on uploads folder"* - where's that folder declaration?

Comment: I searched twice for move_uploaded_file()

Comment: *"A weird problem"* - there's nothing "weird" here, it's what's "missing" and what you're not "doing" and that is, "moving" the file to the folder http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php - Now let's all wait for it................. I should making this an answer instead. But I sense the sun is starting to go down somewhere.

Comment: Check this out http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

Comment: Sorry everyone for late reply, i had to go out. i will try this now what people have suggested with the move file snippets. i will post an update if this was why it wasnt uploading, thanks all

Comment: Ok fixed now, thanks soo much for the help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple: You didn't move that file anywhere, as in `move_uploaded_file()`.

- http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

Base yourself on the following example taken from the manual:

```
<?php
// In PHP versions earlier than 4.1.0, $HTTP_POST_FILES should be used instead
// of $_FILES.

$uploaddir = '/var/www/uploads/';
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);

echo '<pre>';
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
    echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";
} else {
    echo "Possible file upload attack!\n";
}

echo 'Here is some more debugging info:';
print_r($_FILES);

print "</pre>";
```

and check for errors too.

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: ok thanks, i did look at the manual and also on the w3school site too, and i even copied code from there and tweaked it, and that code had this in it, but it still didnt upload then either!, but i will try again and post a reply, if this isnt the fix.

Comment: Ok so yes the file uploads now, i am just annoyed, i tried this method and it kept doing the same, not uploading, now all of a sudden it uploads. thanks everyone

Comment: So now it isn't adding it to the database, but images are uploading?

Comment: @TubeNations Hi, sorry I had left for a while and I'm back now. I'm glad to hear that it all worked for you, *cheers*

Comment: Thanks Fred, i am still learning PHP, i had a coder who did some parts to my site, but now that coder can no longer code for me, so now i had to learn myself. but i am getting better all the time, im just a slow learner :)

Comment: @TubeNations You're welcome. Yeah, I know how it feels being left *"high and dry"* (no code-related), so I can "talk the talk" as it were. Glad to know that you've taken the initiative to learn and it only gets better; *cheers!*

Comment: yeah i am finding it is getting easier as i go along, i just need to remember the basics and don't forget those basics lol, but when you code for hours and hours in a session, it can be very easily forgot at times, and making easy fixable mistakes lol.

Answer (score 1):

I just wanted to post how i did it, thanks to Fred and some other comments others made :)

```
                //Assign Variables
            $username = $user->data['username'];
            #mkdir("uploads/".$username,0755);
            $target_dir = "../uploads/$username-";
            $path = $target_dir . basename($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
            $name = $target_dir . basename($_FILES['image']['name'].$user_id);
            $size = $_FILES['image']['size'];
            $type = $_FILES['image']['type'];



                if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $name)) {
            echo "<h2>Thank you for uploading your banner art - File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n</h2>";
        } else {
            echo "Possible file upload attack!\n";
        }
```

so I also made it so it now puts a username in front of the uploaded images name too.

The form is pretty much the same, I now also made it so that the upload and update open in a nice fancy box :)

https://gyazo.com/e12a03ce01d8f503b8fa2e79f5605809

Thanks again everyone :)